# Pydantic use import path as a field type

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

Let's say I have a project:

```
myproject
--module1
  --foo.py
--module2
  --bar.py
```

the contents of a `foo.py` file:

```
class FooClass:
   def __init__(self, a):
       self.a = a
```

Now, I want to define a Pydantic model in the `bar.py` that has a field of type FooClass, something like this works perfectly:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, InstanceOf

from myproject.module1.foo import FooClass

class BarClass:
    foo: InstaceOf[FooClass]
    x: int
```

The problem arises when I can't have the line `from myproject.module1.foo import FooClass`, maybe because of some circular imports. I was thinking about a custom validator looking like this (a late import in a way):

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, InstanceOf

class BarClass:
    foo: ImportPath['myproject.module1.foo.FooClass']
    x: int
```

Does it even make sense? If so, I'd greatly appreciate any hints on how to implement it.

Comment: To me it does not make sense. I would rather refactor this part of the project to make use of a common/shared module and import it from multiple files/classes.